# Spring Cache Abstraction: How to Deal With java.util.Optional<T>

Tags: spring, hazelcast

We have a lot of code in our code base that's similar to the following interface:

```
public interface SomethingService {
    @Cacheable(value = "singleSomething")
    Optional<Something> fetchSingle(int somethingId);

    // more methods...
}
```

This works fine as long we're only using local caches. But as soon as we're using a distributed cache like Hazelcast, things start to break because `java.util.Optional<T>` is not serializable and thus cannot be cached.

With what I've come up so far to solve this problem:

1. Removing `java.util.Optional<T>` from the method definitions and instead checking for the trusty `null`.
2. Unwrapping `java.util.Optional<T>` before caching the actual value.

I want to avoid (1) because it would involve a lot of refactoring. And I have no idea how to accomplish (2) without implementing my own `org.springframework.cache.Cache`.

What other options do I have? I would prefer a generic (Spring) solution that would work with most distributed caches (Hazelcast, Infinispan, ...) but I would accept a Hazelcast-only option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution would be to register a serializer for the Optional type. Hazelcast has a flexibile serialization API and you can register a serializer for any type.

For more information see the following example:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/serialization/stream-serializer

So something like this:

```
public class OptionalSerializer implements StreamSerializer<Optional> {

@Override
public void write(ObjectDataOutput out, Optional object) throws IOException {
    if(object.isPresent()){
        out.writeObject(object.get());
    }else{
        out.writeObject(null);
    }
}

@Override
public Optional read(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    Object result = in.readObject();
    return result == null?Optional.empty():Optional.of(result);
}

@Override
public int getTypeId() {
    return 0;//todo:
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
}
```

However the solution isn't perfect because this Optional thing will be part of the actual storage. So internally the Optional wrapper is also stored and this can lead to problems with e.g. queries.

Comment: could you elaborate on what is not "perfect" about this solution with some examples because your solution looks good to me. I don't know understand why the "Optional thing will be part of the actual storage" is a problem, or what "problems with queries" you're referring to.